# What's the equivalent of \equation for \begin{equation*}

Tags: environments

I would like to define a new environment, which is based on a starred version of a LaTeX environment.

```
\newenvironment{eq}{\relax
Here is my unnumbered equation:
\begin{equation*}
}{
\end{equation*}
}
```

This all works nicely, except that the `\begin{equation*}` ... `\end{equation*}` confuses tools that check `begin`... `end` pairs are balanced. Had it been the non-starred version of the environment, I would have written:

```
\newenvironment{eq}{\relax
Here is my numbered equation:
\equation
}{
\endequation
}
```

But, what do I do to get the starred version of the environment without confusing tools? Yes, for `equation` I may have been able to use `\[` ... 
`\]`, but what do I do for any other environment?

Comment: and why you not use already defined `\[` and `\]`?

Comment: You should use another editor which is not confused by mismatching `\begin...\end`.

Comment: it is not the editor, but rather `lacheck`: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/lacheck?lang=en

Answer (score 3):

`\equation*` which you could enter as `\csname equation*\endcsname` or by making `*` locally have catcode 11 (letter) so `\equation*` works.  beware of white space control though, your suggested definition using `\equation` would add unwanted spaces, you need `%` and `\ignorespacesafterend`

Comment: you need to deal with the other -- multiline -- environments, which don't necessarily yield gracefully to being redefined as simple commands.

Comment: @barbarabeeton the Op may have to. I don't :-)